Ubuntu 24.04 Graphics issue after latest update
I have been using Ubuntu 24.04 for a couple of months and I barely faced any issues but I got an update couple of days ago and then I am facing some issues related to GPU.
Issues

There are no UI animations.
Some apps has glitch.
Overall laggy experience.
X11 changed to Wayland (not a big deal for me if everything works).

I am sure this is happening after that update because I used Timeshift for system backup and tested restoring before/after update.
Before installing update:

After installing update:


was the update linux kernel?

yes, there was a minor kernel update

From linux-6.8.0.38-generic to linux-6.8.0.39-generic

ok, if you want to help you can go https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu and tell them about it, kernels change pretty fast right now, and for yourself you can test it first and then st up using older kernel, https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version.

Open the "Software & Updates" app, click on "Additional Drivers" and show us which driver you are using. This doesn't seem to be a kernel issue but rather a video card driver problem. As an example, below is what I have: Additional Drivers

Thanks, I solved it myself.
I doubted the graphics drivers, so I went to NVIDIA's website, downloaded the latest driver for my GPU, and installed it.
After reboot everything works like a charm.
